# PowerShell PSCredential Argument List - Path

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to connect to a remote server and do some file copies and moves, etc. The remote server requires authentication.

What do I need to enter in for PSCredential -ArgumentList, argument #1? Is it the path to a particular remote user (let's say "Administartor") like

```
\\SERVER2\Users\Administrator
```

Or is it simply the username like

```
Administrator
```

Or is it the path to the remote resource itself like

```
\\SERVER2\Data\Content
```

...

#### Authenticate the call

```
$Creds = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist "\\Some\Path",$PW
 Copy-Item  $src $destination -Credential $Creds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not how PSCredential objects work.  I think you're overthinking it.

A System.Management.Automation.PSCredential object has two properties: `SecureString Password` and `String UserName`.

`$Creds = Get-Credential`

or

`$Creds = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist "DOMAIN\joebob", $PW`

where $PW is a SecureString object.  One way to create a SecureString:

`PS C:\> $Secure = ConvertTo-SecureString "Pass.1234!" -AsPlainText -Force`

PSCredential documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.pscredential_members(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: The Copy-Item cmdlet, for instance, supports the -Credential argument.  So `Copy-Item C:\list.txt \\Server02\list.txt -Credential $Creds`